# Make or Order begin_dt and end_dt in given format

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having 2 tables tab1 and tab2 below are data present in tab1 and tab2

```
       TAB1
-----------------------    
BEGIN_DT    END_DT
-----------------------
1/5/2016    31/12/2018
-----------------------
1/1/2019    30/9/2020
-----------------------
1/10/2020   
-----------------------

        TAB2    
-----------------------     
BEGIN_DT    END_DT
-----------------------
2/5/2016    30/9/2020
-----------------------
1/10/2020   
-----------------------

       Output   
-----------------------    
BEGIN_DT    END_DT
-----------------------
2/5/2016    31/12/2018
-----------------------
1/1/2019    30/9/2020
-----------------------
1/10/2020   
-----------------------
```

I tried to achieve this with loops but not getting exact result

Comment: No idea; I don't understand which rules have to be applied to TAB1 and TAB2 in order to produce OUTPUT.

Comment: Please add more information describing how the data in TAB1 and TAB2 are used to generate Output

Comment: And include information on the data types of all the columns.  Hopefully, they are all `DATE` data types. But we need to know that.  And whether the output is the results of a `MIN(` or `MAX(` function, etc.  90% of the the time you don't need to loop, just use grouping of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below query:

```
Select case when t2.begin_dt > t1.begin_dt then
          t2.begin_dt
       else
        t1.begin_dt
       end begin_dt,
       case when t2.end_dt > t1.end_dt then
          t1.end_dt
       else
         t2.end_dt
       end end_dt
From
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r1  from tab1)t1,
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r2  from tab2)t2
where r1=r2 and  t2.begin_dt between t1.begin_dt and t1.end_dt
union
Select t1.begin_dt,t1.end_dt    
From
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r1  from tab1)t1,
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r2  from tab2)t2
where r1=r2 and  t2.begin_dt not between t1.begin_dt and t1.end_dt
union
Select distinct t1.begin_dt,
       case when t2.end_dt > t1.end_dt then
          t1.end_dt
       else
         t2.end_dt
       end end_dt
From
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r1  from tab1)t1,
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r2  from tab2)t2
where t1.begin_dt=t2.begin_dt
union
Select case when t2.begin_dt > t1.begin_dt then
          t2.begin_dt
       else
        t1.begin_dt
       end begin_dt,t1.end_dt
From
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r1  from tab1 where end_dt is null)t1,
(Select begin_dt,end_dt,rownum r2  from tab2 where end_dt is null)t2
```

Comment: Thank You for query .It really helped me a lot